Compute the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\text{Ei}(-x)dx$
My idea was to use the Laplace transform using this identity:
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx\right\}=\frac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s}=\frac{F(s)}{s}$$
My first approach was utilizing the proof of this identity, integration by parts:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\text{Ei}(-x)dx=\left[-e^{-x}\text{Ei}(-x)\right]_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x}}{x}dx$$
however, this approach leads me to diverging terms and does not allow me to use Laplace.
And I don't think I can use Laplace straightforwardly because
$$\text{Ei}(-x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}-\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$
Is there a proper way of solving this integral?

Hint Define the family
$$I(a, b) := \int_0^\infty e^{-a x} \operatorname{Ei}(-b x) \,dx, \qquad a, b > 0,$$
of integrals.
Differentiating under the integral sign with respect to $b$ gives
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} = \int_0^\infty e^{-a x} \cdot \frac{e^{-b x}}{b} \,dx = \frac{1}{b (a + b)} .$$

The F.T.C. yields $$\lim_{B \to \infty} I(a, B) - I(a, b) = \int_b^\infty \frac{d\beta}{\beta (a + \beta)} = \frac1a \log \frac{b + a}{b} .$$ Now, $$\lim_{B \to \infty} I(a, B) = 0,$$ so substituting and rearranging gives $$\boxed{I(a, b) = \frac1 a \log \frac{b}{b + a}} .$$


The integral in the question statement is $$\boxed{I(1, 1) = - \log 2}.$$


Woah, thank you for that!!!

You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful.

From A table of integrals of exponential integrals by Geller, Murray; Ng, Edward W, page 197:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}E_1(bx) = \frac{1}{a} \ln\left(1 + \frac{a}{b}\right)$$
where $E_1(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt$

Your integral would correspond to the case $a = 1, b = -1$, and substituting  it on the RHS would equal $\frac{1}{1}\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{-1}\right) = \ln(0)$ and therefore it diverges.

The antiderivative is simple
$$I(a,b)=\int e^{-a x} \,\,\text{Ei}(-b x)\,dx$$
One integration by parts with $u=\text{Ei}(-b x)$
$$I(a,b)=-\frac 1 a e^{-a x} \text{Ei}(-b x)+\frac 1 a\int\frac {e^{-(a+b) x}} x \,dx $$
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\text{Ei}(-((a+b) x))-e^{-a x}   \text{Ei}(-b x)}{a}$$
$$J(a,b)=\int_0^t e^{-a x} \,\,\text{Ei}(-b x)\,dx=$$ Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive
$$J(a,b,t)=\frac 1 a \left(-e^{-a t} \text{Ei}(-b t)+\text{Ei}(-((a+b) t))+\log
   \left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)\right)$$
Asymptotically
$$J(a,b,t)=\frac 1 a \log \left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)+\frac{e^{-(a+b)t}}{b (a+b)  \,t}\Bigg(1-\frac{a+2 b}{b (a+b)\,t}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\Bigg)$$

When integrating by parts, choose $ -e^{-x}+1$ for the antiderivative for $e^{-x}$.
Then$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x} \operatorname{Ei}(-x) \, \mathrm dx = \operatorname{Ei}(-x) \left(-e^{-x}+1 \right)\bigg|_{0}^{\infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-x}}{x} \, \mathrm dx. $$
The boundary term vanishes when $x$ approaches either endpoint, and the integral is a Frullani integral with value $-\ln(2)$.
More generally, for $s>0$, choose $\frac{1}{s} \left(-e^{-sx}+1 \right)$ for the antiderivative of $e^{-sx}$ to get $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx} \operatorname{Ei}(-x) \, \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{s} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(s+1)x}-e^{-x}}{x} \, \mathrm dx = - \frac{\ln(s+1)}{s}.$$
